# Why is $\int\limits_{k-1}^{k} \log x dx< \log k < \int\limits_{k}^{k+1} \log x dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality

In the text it says that since log x is monotonically increasing, the following inequalities follow, but I don't see why they are true:

$$\int\limits_{k-1}^{k} \log x dx< \log k < \int\limits_{k}^{k+1} \log x dx$$

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Since $\log x < \log k$ for $x < k$, we have $\int_{k-1}^k \log x\,dx < \int_{k-1}^k \log k\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't consider that option.